# How to replace a 10 digit sequence using sed

Tags: sed

Using 'sed' I want to replace any 10 digit sequence with 1234567890

This works but is not very elegant

```
echo "code=1111111111" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/1234567890/'
```

This does not work

```
echo "code=1111111111" | sed 's/[0-9]{10}/1234567890/'
```

result

```
code=1111111111
```

Can anyone suggest an simple elegant solution that uses 'sed' ?

Comment: Would you also want to change the sequence of 2's in `beep2222222222111=0000000000`? Another way to ask the same thing: Should only the part after the `=` be considered, and should it _only_ change if it's 10 digits (not more and not fewer)?

Comment: Thanks. I meant only the digits after the equals sign.
And in my case the input would typically only contain a 10 digit number.

Comment: So the issue is not actually about matching ten digits, but to replace whatever comes after the `=`?

Comment: I see your point. Yes you're right. However..
I have many devices each containing a unique identifier (10 digit code) in more than one place.
The script I am preparing will allow for someone to set a new code in all the right files on a particular device. Only one of the files has the format 'code=1234567890'. In other places it is surrounded by different text but will always be a 10 digit number.
So really I just want to match and replace a 10 digit number. So far the solutions provided do point me in the right direction. Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` uses Basic Regular Expression by default, meaning that `{10}` will be treated as plain text.

You can verify this :

```
echo "code=1{10}" | sed 's/[0-9]{10}/1234567890/'
```

Which will output :

```
1234567890
```

In your case, you need to either :

- Use the `-E` option to specify that you want to use Extended Regular Expressions.
- Escape `{` and `}` like this: `\{10\}`.

```
echo "code=1111111111" | sed -E 's/[0-9]{10}/1234567890/'
echo "code=1111111111" | sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}/1234567890/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ERE` regex flavor:

```
$ echo "code=1111111111" | sed -E 's/[0-9]{10}/1234567890/'
code=1234567890
```

Answer (score 4):

Others have already pointed out that you are trying to use a POSIX extended regular expression with `sed`, which by default understands POSIX *basic* regular expressions.  Some (most) implementations of the tool understand extended regular expressions if you use the `-E` option, but you could also change the expression to a basic one by changing `{10}` to `\{10\}`.

However, if you want to be sure that you replace the *correct* ten-digit number, you should probably avoid matching longer numbers and those that occur in other places in the input.

Without knowing more about the input, I would restrict the match by matching the `=` character and the end of the line:

```bash
sed 's/=[0-9]\{10\}$/=1234567890/'
```

This avoids matching longer numbers and ten-digit numbers that do not occur between a `=` and the end of the line.

If you know you need to change the value of the `code` variable (or whatever `code` is), also match that name (here, I'm also assuming the name starts at the start of the line, and I'm capturing the name and replacing it with `\1` in the replacement to reduce duplication):

```bash
sed 's/^\(code\)=[0-9]\{10\}$/\1=1234567890/'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the first sequence of 10 **and not more** ASCII decimal digits with 1234567890 on each line, that should probably be:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^0123456789])[0123456789]{10}([^0123456789]|$)/\112345678900\2/'
```

That is replace only 10 digits (using `[0123456789]` rather than `[0-9]` as the latter can match a lot more characters than just 0123456789 depending on the `sed` implementation and/or locale) preceded by either the beginning of the line or a non-digit and followed by either a non-digit or the end of the line.

That would still replace `1112223334.6` with `1234567890.6` or `1.0000000000e-2` with `1.1234567890e-2` or `0xff0777888999ee` with `0xff1234567890ee` so you may need to adapt depending on what you want and what you may find on the input.

To replace **all** the sequences of 10 **and not more** digits, that could be:

```
sed -E 's/[0123456789]+/\
&\
/g; s/\n[0123456789]{10}\n/123456789/g;s/\n//g'
```

Or you could switch to `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)/1234567890/g'
```

Using the negative look-around operators to check that sequence of 10 decimal digits is neither preceded nor followed by another digit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Kamil Maciorowski

This works nicely

```
echo "code=1111111111" | sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}/1234567890/'
```